# Learning word alignment from nltk

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a parallel corpus for english-german. Is there a way to extract word alignment table from this corpus using nltk? I don't know if nltk.align is supposed to do this. I am unable to figure out from the documentation.

Comment: I cannot see a function `nltk.align` in my NLTK installation (version 3.2.1). However, you should have a look at the `nltk.translate` module; it provides, for example, implementations for all 5 IBM models.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source of the modules in the `nltk.translate` package (previously known as `nltk.align`); you'll find descriptions of the available algorithms and references to the research literature that explains them in more detail.